# Grafana graph jumping / flickering on refresh

Tags: graph, grafana, flicker, amazon-timestream

I am using the latest Grafana 8.2.1 with Amazon Timestream 3.1.1 datasource plugin.

I have noticed that when I use more than one query, the graph will jump / flicker on refresh.

[image]

I have the details reported in [issue 40424](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/40424)

Just wondering if anyone else has experienced the same thing and if there is a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Panel is trying to optimize axe min/max values based on graphed values. Panel is getting those 2 timeseries in different times (executionFinishTime difference is 6 ms), so that is causing flickering.

I would set static `Y-min` and `Y-max` values (e.g. 20, 140 for showed values) to minize that auto optimization of axes. Or you can play also with [soft Y-min/max](https://grafana.com/blog/2021/02/10/how-the-new-time-series-panel-brings-major-performance-improvements-and-new-visualization-features-to-grafana-7.4/#soft-min-and-max-axis-limits).

Comment: Tnx. This is true. I actually was able to make it work playing with axis. But isn't this something that fundamentally should be taken care of? Queries will always return in different times and the gap is inevitable. Isn't there an option that says wait till all the queries have returned and then start plotting?

Comment: @kaptan That's solution only for your case. But what if you have 2 queries, one slow (30sec execution time) and one quick (1sec execution time). Will you be happy if you have to wait 30 seconds until you will see a data first time? That needs better logic. Grafana team is smart, so they may develop better solution for this problem in the future.

Comment: I hear what you are saying. I am surprised that this issue hasn't been causing trouble for anyone else. I think having a toggle in the panel like `Render after all Query Executions` can be helpful.

Comment: You may also use right Y-axis for second time series. Then they will be independent and min/max optimization won't be a problem. IMHO this is edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have flickering problems too. Very bothersome. In my case I perform various readings alternatively every fraction of a second to avoid serial port congestion. Maybe grafana doesn't like the slight difference in time between different measurement series.

Comment: Do you have a workaround?